# Manipulate with a function as a parameter

Tags: manipulate, inputfield

I'm trying to make a Manipulate command to plot the contour lines of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$. I think I should use the "InputField" option somehow, and I thought of something like this:

```
   Manipulate[
              ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], 
              {f, #1-#2 &, InputField[_]}]
```

However, this gives me a slider for $f$, which I don't want, and also changing the function doesn't seem to work.

My question is, how do you work with the Manipulate command when one of the arguments is a function, and more specifically, how do you fix my line of code.

Thanks!

P.S.

I also don't like feeding the function with the # notation, I'd prefer to feed in an expression involving x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both styles are possible

```
Row[{
  Manipulate[ ContourPlot[ a[x, y] == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {{a, #1 - #2 &}}],
  Manipulate[ ContourPlot[       a == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {{a, x - y}}]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

Answering your comment below, you may use the function in many ways. Here I numerically solve a differential equation involving it:

```
Manipulate[
 nd = NDSolve[{(a /. y -> y[x]) == y'[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, -5, 5}];
 GraphicsRow[{
              Plot[y[x] /. nd, {x, -5, 5}],
              ContourPlot[a == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}],
 {{a, -Cos[y] + Sin[x]^2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can this be modified so that the input is still in the elegant terms of x and y, but I can still use it as a function? (i.e. use something like a[x,y]==0).

Comment: @user1337 try `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@a, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}], {{a, x - y == 0}}]`

Comment: Sorry, but to be more specific, what if I want to feed in the function a in terms of x and y, but use it both to plot the contour a[x,y]==0, and to solve the ODE y'[x]==a[x,y[x]]. I mean, working with both a[x,y] and a[x,y[x]] in the same Manipulate, while the UI still in nice symbolic form.

Comment: Actually, the follow up question is far too big to be discussed in the comments. I'll post it separately. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1337 Yep. I think so too. Thanks for the accept

Comment: I'm going to try dealing with it myself first, just in case your'e waiting for my new question ;)

Comment: @user1337 `Manipulate[
 nd = NDSolve[{(a /. y -> y[x]) == y'[x], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, -5, 5}];
 GraphicsRow[{
   Plot[y[x] /. nd, {x, -5, 5}],
   ContourPlot[a == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]}],
 {{a, -Cos[y] + Sin[x]^2}}]`

Comment: Beautiful! thanks